# jQuery not removing selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

this bugs been annoying me a bit now, im having to validate all form data client side before being pushed to an external API

im validating some requirements on user passwords with this function

```
//check passwords match and are strong enough
$(document).on('change', '#password-confirm', function () {

    var $password = $('#password').val();
    var $password_confirmation = $(this).val();

    if ($password.length >= 8) {

        $('#password').parent().removeClass("validationErrors");
        $('#password-confirm').parent().removeClass("validationErrors");
        $('#password-help-block').removeClass("validationErrors").removeClass("passwordValidationErrors");
        console.log($('#password').parent());
        console.log($('#password-confirm').parent());

        if ($password === $password_confirmation) {

            //passwords match check the strengths good enough
            if ($('.strength_meter div').hasClass('veryweak')) {
                //passed validation do something
                $(this).parent().addClass("validationErrors");
            }
            if ($('.strength_meter div').hasClass('weak')) {
                $(this).parent().addClass("validationErrors");
            } else {
                //strong enough
                $('#email').parent().removeClass("validationErrors");
            }
        } else {
            //passwords dont match do something
            $(this).val('Your password do not match');
            $('#password').parent().addClass("validationErrors");
        }
    } else {
        //not long enough throw error
        $('#password').parent().addClass("validationErrors");
        $('#password-confirm').parent().addClass("validationErrors");
        $('#password-help-block').addClass("validationErrors").addClass("passwordValidationErrors");
    }
});
```

The html is as followed

```
   <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-text strength" aria-describedby="password-help-block" aria-required="true" data-password="password">
        <input style="display:none" class="strength" data-password="password" type="text" name="" value=""><a data-password-button="password" href="" class="button_strength">Show Password</a>
        <div class="strength_meter">
            <div data-meter="password"><span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="button button-icon help-block-trigger" data-target="password-help-block"><i class="icon icon-info"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

<div class="input-wrapper field">
                    <input type="password" name="password-confirm" id="password-confirm" class="input-text" aria-required="true">
                </div>
```

When my passwords not long enough it works as expected adding the .validationErrors css class when i then go back make the password up to 8 characters it removes the validationErrors class from the #password parent attribute but not the #password-confirm parent, with no explanation

any ideas????

Comment: Indeed. parent() is de direct parent of de specific element.

Comment: I see you are wiring it up on `#password-confirm` `change` event, are you typing in the `#password` or `#password-confirm` field? Any changes in `#password` field will not invoke you code.

Comment: i missed pasting the element here into my question i updated it, the element is present on page when dom loads

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt no im tryping into the #password-confirm input, the jquery runs past the

if ($password.length >= 8) {

and fires these two remove commands

   $('#password').parent().removeClass("validationErrors");

    $('#password-help-block').removeClass("validationErrors").removeClass("passwordValidationErrors");


just not the #password-confirm which is in the middle of these two rules

Comment: Can you create a snippet in your question that shows the problem?

Comment: Well is the password weak? Than it will add the class back to that element.